# using the find function from algorithm on vector

Tags: c++, vector, iterator, find, stl-algorithm

I want to use the find function from the algorithm library on a vector object. The vector object is a vector of customers, (Customer is a class I made). I first ran it and it gave me an error in `stl_algo.h`. I search the web for it and I searched here for it too, I found a question here about it and I ran the same code, but I still got that error.

My code is here:

Header File:

```
#include <string>
#include <sstream>
#include <map>
#include <vector>

using namespace std;

enum Status {ACTIVE, INACTIVE};

class Customer {
    private:
        // ID Database class for storing customers' ids
        class IdDB {
            private:
                friend class Customer;

                // member field
                static map <string, int> idList;

                // member function
                static int getNumber (const string &threeLetters) {
                    map<string, int>::iterator i = idList.find(threeLetters);

                    if (i == idList.end()) {
                        idList.insert(pair <string, int> (threeLetters, 0));
                        return 0;
                    }else{
                        return ++(i->second);
                    }
                }
        };

        string id;
        string name;
        string address;
        Status status;

        void makeId () {
            string threeLetters = name.substr(0, 3);
            int idNum = IdDB::getNumber(threeLetters);

            stringstream oss;
            oss << threeLetters << idNum;
            id = oss.str();
        }

    public:
        Customer (const string&, const string&, const Status);

        // Accessor Methods
        string &getId ();
        string &getName ();
        string &getAddress ();
        Status getStatus ();

        // Mutator Methods
        void setAddress (const string&);
        void setStatus (const Status);

        // Misc. Methods
        void printStatus ();

        // Equality Operator Overloading
        friend bool operator == (Customer&, Customer&);
};

class CustomerDB {
    private:
        static vector<Customer> customersList;

    public:
        static void addCustomer (const Customer&);
        static void deleteCustomer (Customer&);
};
```

Source Code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <algorithm>
#include "Customer.h"

using namespace std;

map<string, int> Customer::IdDB::idList;

Customer::Customer (const string &cName, const string &cAddress, const Status cStatus) : name(cName), address(cAddress), status(cStatus) {
    makeId();
}

// Accessor Methods
string &Customer::getId () { return id; }
string &Customer::getName () { return name; }
string &Customer::getAddress () { return address; }
Status Customer::getStatus () { return status; }

// Mutator Methods
void Customer::setAddress (const string &newAddress) { address = newAddress; }
void Customer::setStatus (const Status newStatus) { status = newStatus; }

// Misc. Methods
void Customer::printStatus () {
    if (status == ACTIVE)
        cout << "Active";
    else
        cout << "In-Active";
}

vector<Customer> CustomerDB::customersList;

void CustomerDB::addCustomer (const Customer &customer) {
    customersList.push_back(customer);
}

void CustomerDB::deleteCustomer (Customer &customer) {
    vector<Customer>::iterator i;
    i = find(customersList.begin(), customersList.end(), customer); // getting error in here
}

// Equality Operator Overloading
bool operator == (Customer &cust1, Customer &cust2) {
    return cust1.getId() == cust2.getId();
}
```

after building with Code::Blocks, I got this,

in header file `stl_algo.h`:

```
    }

  /// This is an overload used by find() for the RAI case.
  template<typename _RandomAccessIterator, typename _Tp>
    _RandomAccessIterator
    __find(_RandomAccessIterator __first, _RandomAccessIterator __last,
       const _Tp& __val, random_access_iterator_tag)
    {
      typename iterator_traits<_RandomAccessIterator>::difference_type
    __trip_count = (__last - __first) >> 2;

      for (; __trip_count > 0; --__trip_count)
    {
      if (*__first == __val) // error in here exactly getting a red block
        return __first;
      ++__first;

      if (*__first == __val)
        return __first;
      ++__first;

      if (*__first == __val)
        return __first;
```

Thanks

EDIT: Here is the build log

```
Compiling: C:\Users\KiKo-SaMa\Desktop\C++\DVD_App\Customer.cpp
In file included from c:\mingw\bin\../lib/gcc/mingw32/4.6.2/include/c++/algorithm:63:0,
                 from C:\Users\KiKo-SaMa\Desktop\C++\DVD_App\Customer.cpp:5:
c:\mingw\bin\../lib/gcc/mingw32/4.6.2/include/c++/bits/stl_algo.h: In function '_RandomAccessIterator std::__find(_RandomAccessIterator, _RandomAccessIterator, const _Tp&, std::random_access_iterator_tag) [with _RandomAccessIterator = __gnu_cxx::__normal_iterator<Customer*, std::vector<Customer> >, _Tp = Customer]':
c:\mingw\bin\../lib/gcc/mingw32/4.6.2/include/c++/bits/stl_algo.h:4403:45:   instantiated from '_IIter std::find(_IIter, _IIter, const _Tp&) [with _IIter = __gnu_cxx::__normal_iterator<Customer*, std::vector<Customer> >, _Tp = Customer]'
C:\Users\KiKo-SaMa\Desktop\C++\DVD_App\Customer.cpp:42:66:   instantiated from here
c:\mingw\bin\../lib/gcc/mingw32/4.6.2/include/c++/bits/stl_algo.h:162:4: error: no match for 'operator==' in '__first.__gnu_cxx::__normal_iterator<_Iterator, _Container>::operator* [with _Iterator = Customer*, _Container = std::vector<Customer>, __gnu_cxx::__normal_iterator<_Iterator, _Container>::reference = Customer&]() == __val'
c:\mingw\bin\../lib/gcc/mingw32/4.6.2/include/c++/bits/stl_algo.h:162:4: note: candidates are:
c:\mingw\bin\../lib/gcc/mingw32/4.6.2/include/c++/bits/postypes.h:218:5: note: template<class _StateT> bool std::operator==(const std::fpos<_StateT>&, const std::fpos<_StateT>&)
c:\mingw\bin\../lib/gcc/mingw32/4.6.2/include/c++/bits/stl_pair.h:201:5: note: template<class _T1, class _T2> bool std::operator==(const std::pair<_T1, _T2>&, const std::pair<_T1, _T2>&)
c:\mingw\bin\../lib/gcc/mingw32/4.6.2/include/c++/bits/stl_iterator.h:285:5: note: template<class _Iterator> bool std::operator==(const std::reverse_iterator<_Iterator>&, const std::reverse_iterator<_Iterator>&)
c:\mingw\bin\../lib/gcc/mingw32/4.6.2/include/c++/bits/stl_iterator.h:335:5: note: template<class _IteratorL, class _IteratorR> bool std::operator==(const std::reverse_iterator<_IteratorL>&, const std::reverse_iterator<_IteratorR>&)
c:\mingw\bin\../lib/gcc/mingw32/4.6.2/include/c++/bits/allocator.h:122:5: note: template<class _T1, class _T2> bool std::operator==(const std::allocator<_T1>&, const std::allocator<_T2>&)
c:\mingw\bin\../lib/gcc/mingw32/4.6.2/include/c++/bits/allocator.h:127:5: note: template<class _Tp> bool std::operator==(const std::allocator<_Tp1>&, const std::allocator<_Tp1>&)
c:\mingw\bin\../lib/gcc/mingw32/4.6.2/include/c++/bits/basic_string.h:2427:5: note: template<class _CharT, class _Traits, class _Alloc> bool std::operator==(const std::basic_string<_CharT, _Traits, _Alloc>&, const std::basic_string<_CharT, _Traits, _Alloc>&)
c:\mingw\bin\../lib/gcc/mingw32/4.6.2/include/c++/bits/basic_string.h:2434:5: note: template<class _CharT> typename __gnu_cxx::__enable_if<std::__is_char<_Tp>::__value, bool>::__type std::operator==(const std::basic_string<_CharT>&, const std::basic_string<_CharT>&)
c:\mingw\bin\../lib/gcc/mingw32/4.6.2/include/c++/bits/basic_string.h:2448:5: note: template<class _CharT, class _Traits, class _Alloc> bool std::operator==(const _CharT*, const std::basic_string<_CharT, _Traits, _Alloc>&)
c:\mingw\bin\../lib/gcc/mingw32/4.6.2/include/c++/bits/basic_string.h:2460:5: note: template<class _CharT, class _Traits, class _Alloc> bool std::operator==(const std::basic_string<_CharT, _Traits, _Alloc>&, const _CharT*)
c:\mingw\bin\../lib/gcc/mingw32/4.6.2/include/c++/bits/streambuf_iterator.h:194:5: note: template<class _CharT, class _Traits> bool std::operator==(const std::istreambuf_iterator<_CharT, _Traits>&, const std::istreambuf_iterator<_CharT, _Traits>&)
c:\mingw\bin\../lib/gcc/mingw32/4.6.2/include/c++/bits/stl_tree.h:309:5: note: template<class _Val> bool std::operator==(const std::_Rb_tree_iterator<_Tp>&, const std::_Rb_tree_const_iterator<_Val>&)
c:\mingw\bin\../lib/gcc/mingw32/4.6.2/include/c++/bits/stl_tree.h:846:5: note: template<class _Key, class _Val, class _KeyOfValue, class _Compare, class _Alloc> bool std::operator==(const std::_Rb_tree<_Key, _Val, _KeyOfValue, _Compare, _Alloc>&, const std::_Rb_tree<_Key, _Val, _KeyOfValue, _Compare, _Alloc>&)
c:\mingw\bin\../lib/gcc/mingw32/4.6.2/include/c++/bits/stl_map.h:877:5: note: template<class _Key, class _Tp, class _Compare, class _Alloc> bool std::operator==(const std::map<_Key, _Tp, _Compare, _Alloc>&, const std::map<_Key, _Tp, _Compare, _Alloc>&)
c:\mingw\bin\../lib/gcc/mingw32/4.6.2/include/c++/bits/stl_multimap.h:795:5: note: template<class _Key, class _Tp, class _Compare, class _Alloc> bool std::operator==(const std::multimap<_Key, _Tp, _Compare, _Alloc>&, const std::multimap<_Key, _Tp, _Compare, _Alloc>&)
c:\mingw\bin\../lib/gcc/mingw32/4.6.2/include/c++/bits/stl_vector.h:1273:5: note: template<class _Tp, class _Alloc> bool std::operator==(const std::vector<_Tp, _Alloc>&, const std::vector<_Tp, _Alloc>&)
C:\Users\KiKo-SaMa\Desktop\C++\DVD_App\Customer.cpp:46:6: note: bool operator==(Customer&, Customer&)
C:\Users\KiKo-SaMa\Desktop\C++\DVD_App\Customer.cpp:46:6: note:   no known conversion for argument 2 from 'const Customer' to 'Customer&'
c:\mingw\bin\../lib/gcc/mingw32/4.6.2/include/c++/bits/stl_algo.h:4403:45:   instantiated from '_IIter std::find(_IIter, _IIter, const _Tp&) [with _IIter = __gnu_cxx::__normal_iterator<Customer*, std::vector<Customer> >, _Tp = Customer]'
C:\Users\KiKo-SaMa\Desktop\C++\DVD_App\Customer.cpp:42:66:   instantiated from here
c:\mingw\bin\../lib/gcc/mingw32/4.6.2/include/c++/bits/stl_algo.h:166:4: error: no match for 'operator==' in '__first.__gnu_cxx::__normal_iterator<_Iterator, _Container>::operator* [with _Iterator = Customer*, _Container = std::vector<Customer>, __gnu_cxx::__normal_iterator<_Iterator, _Container>::reference = Customer&]() == __val'
c:\mingw\bin\../lib/gcc/mingw32/4.6.2/include/c++/bits/stl_algo.h:166:4: note: candidates are:
c:\mingw\bin\../lib/gcc/mingw32/4.6.2/include/c++/bits/postypes.h:218:5: note: template<class _StateT> bool std::operator==(const std::fpos<_StateT>&, const std::fpos<_StateT>&)
c:\mingw\bin\../lib/gcc/mingw32/4.6.2/include/c++/bits/stl_pair.h:201:5: note: template<class _T1, class _T2> bool std::operator==(const std::pair<_T1, _T2>&, const std::pair<_T1, _T2>&)
c:\mingw\bin\../lib/gcc/mingw32/4.6.2/include/c++/bits/stl_iterator.h:285:5: note: template<class _Iterator> bool std::operator==(const std::reverse_iterator<_Iterator>&, const std::reverse_iterator<_Iterator>&)
c:\mingw\bin\../lib/gcc/mingw32/4.6.2/include/c++/bits/stl_iterator.h:335:5: note: template<class _IteratorL, class _IteratorR> bool std::operator==(const std::reverse_iterator<_IteratorL>&, const std::reverse_iterator<_IteratorR>&)
c:\mingw\bin\../lib/gcc/mingw32/4.6.2/include/c++/bits/allocator.h:122:5: note: template<class _T1, class _T2> bool std::operator==(const std::allocator<_T1>&, const std::allocator<_T2>&)
c:\mingw\bin\../lib/gcc/mingw32/4.6.2/include/c++/bits/allocator.h:127:5: note: template<class _Tp> bool std::operator==(const std::allocator<_Tp1>&, const std::allocator<_Tp1>&)
c:\mingw\bin\../lib/gcc/mingw32/4.6.2/include/c++/bits/basic_string.h:2427:5: note: template<class _CharT, class _Traits, class _Alloc> bool std::operator==(const std::basic_string<_CharT, _Traits, _Alloc>&, const std::basic_string<_CharT, _Traits, _Alloc>&)
c:\mingw\bin\../lib/gcc/mingw32/4.6.2/include/c++/bits/basic_string.h:2434:5: note: template<class _CharT> typename __gnu_cxx::__enable_if<std::__is_char<_Tp>::__value, bool>::__type std::operator==(const std::basic_string<_CharT>&, const std::basic_string<_CharT>&)
c:\mingw\bin\../lib/gcc/mingw32/4.6.2/include/c++/bits/basic_string.h:2448:5: note: template<class _CharT, class _Traits, class _Alloc> bool std::operator==(const _CharT*, const std::basic_string<_CharT, _Traits, _Alloc>&)
c:\mingw\bin\../lib/gcc/mingw32/4.6.2/include/c++/bits/basic_string.h:2460:5: note: template<class _CharT, class _Traits, class _Alloc> bool std::operator==(const std::basic_string<_CharT, _Traits, _Alloc>&, const _CharT*)
c:\mingw\bin\../lib/gcc/mingw32/4.6.2/include/c++/bits/streambuf_iterator.h:194:5: note: template<class _CharT, class _Traits> bool std::operator==(const std::istreambuf_iterator<_CharT, _Traits>&, const std::istreambuf_iterator<_CharT, _Traits>&)
c:\mingw\bin\../lib/gcc/mingw32/4.6.2/include/c++/bits/stl_tree.h:309:5: note: template<class _Val> bool std::operator==(const std::_Rb_tree_iterator<_Tp>&, const std::_Rb_tree_const_iterator<_Val>&)
c:\mingw\bin\../lib/gcc/mingw32/4.6.2/include/c++/bits/stl_tree.h:846:5: note: template<class _Key, class _Val, class _KeyOfValue, class _Compare, class _Alloc> bool std::operator==(const std::_Rb_tree<_Key, _Val, _KeyOfValue, _Compare, _Alloc>&, const std::_Rb_tree<_Key, _Val, _KeyOfValue, _Compare, _Alloc>&)
c:\mingw\bin\../lib/gcc/mingw32/4.6.2/include/c++/bits/stl_map.h:877:5: note: template<class _Key, class _Tp, class _Compare, class _Alloc> bool std::operator==(const std::map<_Key, _Tp, _Compare, _Alloc>&, const std::map<_Key, _Tp, _Compare, _Alloc>&)
c:\mingw\bin\../lib/gcc/mingw32/4.6.2/include/c++/bits/stl_multimap.h:795:5: note: template<class _Key, class _Tp, class _Compare, class _Alloc> bool std::operator==(const std::multimap<_Key, _Tp, _Compare, _Alloc>&, const std::multimap<_Key, _Tp, _Compare, _Alloc>&)
c:\mingw\bin\../lib/gcc/mingw32/4.6.2/include/c++/bits/stl_vector.h:1273:5: note: template<class _Tp, class _Alloc> bool std::operator==(const std::vector<_Tp, _Alloc>&, const std::vector<_Tp, _Alloc>&)
C:\Users\KiKo-SaMa\Desktop\C++\DVD_App\Customer.cpp:46:6: note: bool operator==(Customer&, Customer&)
C:\Users\KiKo-SaMa\Desktop\C++\DVD_App\Customer.cpp:46:6: note:   no known conversion for argument 2 from 'const Customer' to 'Customer&'
c:\mingw\bin\../lib/gcc/mingw32/4.6.2/include/c++/bits/stl_algo.h:170:4: error: no match for 'operator==' in '__first.__gnu_cxx::__normal_iterator<_Iterator, _Container>::operator* [with _Iterator = Customer*, _Container = std::vector<Customer>, __gnu_cxx::__normal_iterator<_Iterator, _Container>::reference = Customer&]() == __val'
c:\mingw\bin\../lib/gcc/mingw32/4.6.2/include/c++/bits/stl_algo.h:170:4: note: candidates are:
c:\mingw\bin\../lib/gcc/mingw32/4.6.2/include/c++/bits/postypes.h:218:5: note: template<class _StateT> bool std::operator==(const std::fpos<_StateT>&, const std::fpos<_StateT>&)
c:\mingw\bin\../lib/gcc/mingw32/4.6.2/include/c++/bits/stl_pair.h:201:5: note: template<class _T1, class _T2> bool std::operator==(const std::pair<_T1, _T2>&, const std::pair<_T1, _T2>&)
c:\mingw\bin\../lib/gcc/mingw32/4.6.2/include/c++/bits/stl_iterator.h:285:5: note: template<class _Iterator> bool std::operator==(const std::reverse_iterator<_Iterator>&, const std::reverse_iterator<_Iterator>&)
c:\mingw\bin\../lib/gcc/mingw32/4.6.2/include/c++/bits/stl_iterator.h:335:5: note: template<class _IteratorL, class _IteratorR> bool std::operator==(const std::reverse_iterator<_IteratorL>&, const std::reverse_iterator<_IteratorR>&)
c:\mingw\bin\../lib/gcc/mingw32/4.6.2/include/c++/bits/allocator.h:122:5: note: template<class _T1, class _T2> bool std::operator==(const std::allocator<_T1>&, const std::allocator<_T2>&)
c:\mingw\bin\../lib/gcc/mingw32/4.6.2/include/c++/bits/allocator.h:127:5: note: template<class _Tp> bool std::operator==(const std::allocator<_Tp1>&, const std::allocator<_Tp1>&)
c:\mingw\bin\../lib/gcc/mingw32/4.6.2/include/c++/bits/basic_string.h:2427:5: note: template<class _CharT, class _Traits, class _Alloc> bool std::operator==(const std::basic_string<_CharT, _Traits, _Alloc>&, const std::basic_string<_CharT, _Traits, _Alloc>&)
c:\mingw\bin\../lib/gcc/mingw32/4.6.2/include/c++/bits/basic_string.h:2434:5: note: template<class _CharT> typename __gnu_cxx::__enable_if<std::__is_char<_Tp>::__value, bool>::__type std::operator==(const std::basic_string<_CharT>&, const std::basic_string<_CharT>&)
Process terminated with status 1 (0 minutes, 1 seconds)
50 errors, 0 warnings
```

Comment: when I compile it using command prompt I get a non-ending lines of code not undertsanding anything, but when building it, its not building and giving error

Comment: Without seeing the error, I will guess that your `operator==` needs to take `const Cusstomer&` objects instead of just `Customer&` objects.

Comment: @Chad: Thanks for the help, it builded past the find function, but now it gives a error in the body of the operator == function

Comment: Which is because `Customer::getId()` is not `const`.  Think about that function, does an accessor method require the ability to modify the object's state?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should work on your const correctness, the problem is that your equality comparator takes the arguments by non const reference, but the last argument to `find` is taken by `const` reference, which means that the compiler cannot use it there.

Incidentally, once you add the `const` there you will be forced to add `const` accessors to the data. Also, if your operator only uses the public interface there is no need to declare it as a friend

Comment: I made the accessor functions const also, but now i'm getting `invalid initialization of reference` to the function that return `string&` only

Comment: @aizen92: A function declared `const` cannot return a non-const reference, as that would break the contract. You need to return a `const std::string&` (another note: never employ `using directives` in headers!). If you need to have both a mutating and a const accessor you will need to provide both.

Answer (score 0):

CodeBlocks may give errors about the stl files however they are not actually the errors. It shows the related stl file of your error.

Comment: yes it is not the best answer to this thread but I just want to mention the different error mechanism in CodeBlocks with respect to other compilers.